# Recursive function in ruby is overwriting nested attributes of cloned(object.dup) variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, clone, dup

I have a hash like this:

```
entity = {1=> nil, 2 => {3 => nil, 4 => 1}}
```

I wrote a function which can remove the null values of the given entity using recursion.

```
def clear_null_values(entity)
   entity.each do |key, value|
     if value == nil || value.blank?
       entity.delete(key)
     elsif value.is_a? Hash
       clear_null_values(value)
       entity.delete(key) if value.blank?
     end
   end
end
```

And also I need the original entity as well for other purposes. So I duplicated the hash variable and then cleared the null values.

```
final_entity = entity.dup
clear_null_values(entity)
puts entity
puts final_entity
```

Result:

```
{2 => {4 => 1}}
{1=> nil, 2 => {4 => 1}} # the nested values are overwritten.
```

Ideally, the final_entity should be the same as original entity.

Question1: Why is the `entity.dup` copying only outerhash?

Question2: How to make final_entity the exactly copy of original entity i.e., even if we modify entity then also final_entity shouldn't change?

Comment: I understand that you want to compute `{2 => {4 => 1}}`, but do not understand how `{1=> nil, 2 => {4 => 1}}` is determined, considering that it contains only one of the `nil` values in `entity`.I believe that your question needs a Rails tag as `blank` is not a Ruby method.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Updated the question with tags and some more explanation.

Comment: I understand that you want to compute `{2 => {4 => 1}}`, but do not understand the criteria for the construction of `{1=> nil, 2 => {4 => 1}}`, considering that it contains only one of the `nil` values in `entity`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland There's no criteria for constructing `{1=> nil, 2 => {4 => 1}}` since the badly worded question is how to avoid this result and have final_entity == original entity, a problem arising from `entity.dup` only applying to the outermost hash.

Comment: @Michael, I see. The second line after "result" is the OP's incorrect result, not the desired result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [`deep_dup`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_dup) instead, your original code only `dup`-ed the outermost hash.

```
final_entity = entity.deep_dup
clear_null_values(entity)
puts entity
puts final_entity
```

Outputs:

```
{2=>{4=>1}}
{1=>nil, 2=>{3=>nil, 4=>1}}
```

Note: Rails also adds [`Hash#compact`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-compact), which you could use to simplify `clear_null_values`.

Comment: `deep_dup` worked like a charm. Thanks for the other suggestion suggestion, but I am using Rails 3.2, so Hash#compact won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It would be cleaner, in my opinion, to compute the hash stripped of `nil` values by operating on `entities` directly, rather than on a copy of it.

```
def clear_null_values(entity)
  entity.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),h|
    next if v.nil?
    h[k] = Hash === v ? clear_null_values(v) : v
  end
end

entities = { 1=>nil, 2=>{ 3=>nil, 4=>1 } }

clear_null_values entities
  #=> {2=>{4=>1}}
```

We can confirm `entities` was not mutated.

```
entities
  #=> {1=>nil, 2=>{3=>nil, 4=>1}}
```

Comment: I agree, would be better to return a new value instead of having to `dup` and modifying in place. Made a different version of your approach for fun: https://gist.github.com/citizen428/03006bc4dd40ce5a8323275b7c1fe0cc

Comment: @MichaelKohl, your refinement is an improvement, so I've edited my 
 answer to use it. Thanks.